# MongoDB - Find single dates before and after today

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to write a query to find 2 individual documents dated before and after today, I need the values returned as a cursor as this is a Meteor publication (Perhaps not relevant).

I am currently using this

```
const today = new Date(); 
const before = db.lesson.findOne({lsn_id:kjsflf, lsn_dt:{$lte:today}}, {limit:1});
const after = db.lesson.findOne({lsn_id:kjsflf, lsn_dt:{$gte:today}}, {limit:1});
```

Ideally the result would be something like this:

```
return db.lesson.find({BEST QUERY EVER});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to combine these two queries you can try using MongoDB's $or:

```
    db.lesson.find({
     lsn_id: kjsflf,
     $or: [
       { lsn_dt: { $lte: today }},
       { lsn_dt: { $gte: today }}
     ]}, { limit: 2 });
```

This works well if there only exists one and only one document before "today" and one and only one document after "today".  If there are other documents it will retrieve the first two documents it finds.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: Thanks, I think I will have to add a state to the lesson, so I can query the most recent completed lesson and the soonest incomplete.

Comment: You can also use .sort() and .limit() to arrange the dates to grab the first one to match a query too if need be.  But you still would have to use two calls. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/